# How to Set ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

I need  help to make listview adapter. Below is code please make the adapter both value name with roomid.

```
JSONArray rooms = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rooms");
     for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject room = rooms.getJSONObject(i);
       String name = room.optString("room");
       String roomid = room.optString("roomid");
      final RoomModel sched = new RoomModel();
       sched.setName(name);
       sched.setroomId(roomid);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);}        
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
```

**RoomModel.java**

```
public class RoomModel {
    private  String name, id,  roomid;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public String getroomId() {
    return roomid;
}

public void setroomId(String roomid) {
    this.roomid = roomid;
}
}
```

Comment: Question is not at all clear can you please elaborate

Comment: You are asking for code, not fixing **existing** code. This question will be downvoted soon, it is unclear, and not formatted properly. Look at some listView tutorials, they will get you started well.

Comment: Why are you ordering us to do this and those ? what have you tried ?

Comment: _Frendz Please Write Here the Code Of Adapter_ NO we won't.

Comment: Guys this guy is actually asking for help. His english isnt great :) I tried editing his question though its pretty much hard to edit whatever he had written :) So please ignore and consider it as his request :) Am feeling guilty as though I edited his question couldnt help him much :( @shareef khan : buddy try writing question with bit more clarity

Comment: I want to need help to making Array Adapter Code :(

Comment: Frendz Please Write Here the Code Of Adapter NO we won't. Yes its right

Comment: ok lemme help man :) Whats your issue??? What error are you facing??? You wanna know how to write custom adadpter is that all???

Comment: @SandeepBhandari I have added some hints as per your request. We can't provide the exact code as he needs. Its not a suitable question for stackoverflow. We cant help him if he didn't try.

Comment: I understand :) Thanks a lot for your help :) I was feeling guilty that I couldn't help him so requested all of you :) Hope he learnt his lesson :) that he should try before asking here :) Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following Adapter......

```
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context con;
        ArrayList<your type> mlist;
        RoomModel sched;

        public MyAdapter(Context con,ArrayList<your type> mlist )
        {
            this.con=con;
            this.mlist=mlist;

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mlist.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mlist[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      sched=mlist.get(position);
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout,parent,false);


        TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        tv1.setText(sched.getId());

       TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        tv2.setText(sched.getName());

       TextView tv3=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.your_textview);
        tv3.setText(sched.getroomId());

            return convertView;
        }

  }
```

and change the following code.

```
JSONArray rooms = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rooms");
     for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject room = rooms.getJSONObject(i);
       String name = room.optString("room");
       String roomid = room.optString("roomid");
      final RoomModel sched = new RoomModel();
       sched.setName(name);
       sched.setroomId(roomid);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(sched);}        
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ChatlistView);
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(this,CustomListViewValuesArr);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK as requested by Sandeep, I will give you simple hint but I can't give you full codes that you can directly copy and paste. Just follow instructions

Create an XML file for single item of the list which may have certain elements as you need, for example It's `single_item.xml` which has 3 `TextView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sample Id"
        android:textColor="#0414f4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Sample Title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample body"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and after getting the reference of `listView` from main layout set the adapter like this, And here `modelList` is an `ArrayList`.

```
    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.single_item, modelList);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then the class `CustomAdapter` looks like this

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {    
    ArrayList<Model> modelList;
    Context context;    

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Model> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.modelList = objects;
        this.context = context;

    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item,parent,false);

        }

        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView tvId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        TextView tvBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBody);



        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        tvId.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
        tvTitle.setText(model.getroomId());
        tvBody.setText(model.getName());

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;


    }
}
```

**NOTE :** I have commented and made it simple as possible to help you. Hope this may help. You can comment if any problem raised.

Comment: Thanks buddy for considering my request :) May god bless u :) Happy coding :)